# changing dynamically feed content

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to change my data content `.feedback p, .profile-title h4, .profile-title p, .profile img` with different data assets, but however I only get randomized with the same thing even if I change to `wordsArray` with different data, and naming. how can I achieve dynamic change in the content of each element?

```
<article class="feedback">
  <figure class="quotes">
    <img src="dummy" alt="dummy">
  </figure>
  <p class="feedback-text">dummy</p>
  <div class="profile">
    <figure>
      <img src="dummy" alt="dummy">
    </figure>

    <div class="profile-title">
      <h4>dummy</h4>
      <p>dummy</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</article>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
  $(function () {
    count = 0;
    wordsArray = ["Beta", "Gamma", "Delta", "Alpha"];
    setInterval(function () {
      count++;
      $('.feedback .feedback-text, .profile-title h4, .profile img').fadeOut(400, function () {
        $(this).text(wordsArray[count % wordsArray.length]).fadeIn(400);
      });
    }, 2000);
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Wait for the DOM to be loaded, like this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    count = 0;
    wordsArray = ["Beta", "Gamma", "Delta", "Alpha"];
    setInterval(function () {
      count++;
      $('.feedback .feedback-text, .profile-title h4, .profile img').fadeOut(400, function () {
        $(this).text(wordsArray[count % wordsArray.length]).fadeIn(400);
      });
    }, 2000);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<article class="feedback">
  <figure class="quotes">
    <img src="dummy" alt="dummy">
  </figure>
  <p class="feedback-text">dummy</p>
  <div class="profile">
    <figure>
      <img src="dummy" alt="dummy">
    </figure>

    <div class="profile-title">
      <h4>dummy</h4>
      <p>dummy</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</article>
```